# What is the default maximum number of workitems that can be associated to a commit?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Referring to the "TFS/Devops Server" functionality of linking workitems to a commit described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/), what is the maximum number of workitems that can be associated to a single commit message? Is there any way to increase this number?

Comment: Are you asking how many work items a single commit can reference? Like "Fix #1, #2 and #3"?

Comment: Yes, in a single commit. It seems that max number is 50. Is there any way to increase this number? (I'm still using an old version of TFS: 2017 update 1 on premises, I'm using git repository)

Comment: Don't you think that you have different problems when you want to reference more than 50 work items in a single commit? But I don't know whether this limit is documented somewhere or that it can be changed. Anyway see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/38322/tfs-2017-update1-associated-work-items-for-a-build.html

Answer (score 1):

By default it shows the top 50 suggested work items to be linked, however it's not limited to only link 50 work items to that commit.

We can enter a keyword/ID to filter the work items and then select the ones to link. But it also cannot show all of them in the UI, we can click the `Show more` link to show another part of the work items. You can also call the REST API to check all of the linked work items for that commit.

So, seems no count of work items limits to link to a commit there. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: @user35631 Have you checked the reply? Is that helpful?